Как увеличить границу переноса строки (soft-wrap) в ide Goland?
Не могу найти как настроить границу для Soft-wrap в Goland IDE, граница примерно у меня тут:

И у меня остается огромная часть экрана неиспользуемой


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

@aleksandrbarakin Ну тут как раз скришнот к месту, вопрос же про редактор.
